# Why is a RichEditableText control losing focus when clicking inside it?

Tags: apache-flex, events, flex4, focus

My app creates a `RichEditableText` in response to a button click and then sets the focus on the control So, User can start typing immediately.

However, it seems that a `focusOut` event is dispatched for this control the moment the user clicks inside it. It seems to momentarily lose focus and then get it back. To the user this is invisible, but the app code sees `focusIn` and `focusOut` events being fired, and it messes things up since there's some logic that needs to run when the control **actually** loses focus.

So, any idea why the `RichEditableText` is losing focus? I can't seem to determine what triggers the focus change. If I put a breakpoint inside the `focusOut` event I don't see anything above the `focusOut` event, so it's hard to investigate.

Comment: You'll have to provide some code: I made a [simple test](http://www.privatepaste.com/7661fc6da6) and can't reproduce the behaviour you describe.

Comment: yea, I know, but the code is incredibly complex and shaving it down to a minimal example is really hard in this case.